# Fusion multiple LaserScans to PointCloud

Tags: ros, slam, lidar

I am currently trying to do 3D SLAM with two 2D Lidars and possibly additional IMU in ROS. However, there seems to be no ROS package available to meet my needs. The closest one would be laser_pipeline stack, but the documentation only tells me about fusioning LaserScans from "one source" although what I need is fusioning vertical scan and horizontal scan into one 3D PointCloud2. So I currently need another package to fusion scans from different sources. Anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you need a package for that instead of quickly writing the function yourself?

Comment: @FooTheBar Because I'm pretty new in ROS? Even if I try to, it would take weeks to do that for me.

Comment: What would take weeks? To get the transformation between the Lidars?

Comment: @FooTheBar It seems that my problem is a very simple thing to you. Sharing some ideas about it would be much helpful, isn't it?

Comment: Then you first have to say what _exactly_ is the problem? Do you know the transformation between the two sensors?

Comment: Well, there's currently no "actual" machine in my hand, and I am not seeking about some specific ways to apply for my machine. Also, I already said that I need to fusion two 2d laserscans frame by frame, given what I said, it would be shaped like '十' which would not be hard to imagine.

Comment: I completely understand what you are describing, but you are not saying where your problem is. Do you have problems to manipulate the data structures?

Comment: I can't see why you're consistently saying "You are not say what your problem is". Anyway, it makes sense that I am not good at  "manipulating data structures". I also do not have such ability to create new package that I need right now, and that's why I am questioning here. Very simple question then: Where is a package do I need?

Comment: @FooTheBar Nobody seems to know how to perform 3D SLAM with 2D Lidars... for 10 days nobody is answering my questions in other sites. Very thankful for your answers, but I have pretty much low understanding in ROS itself right now, so I just can't do what seems obvious to do in you and my head.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* anymate98, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MarkBooth Thanks for the tips. However, I'm not able to make this question any more clear than this. Along with absence of real machine for the simulation, I actually have only one lidar right now, and that means everything here is just a "plan". I don't even know how my machine looks like right now! I'm pretty sure it is the reason that makes my quesetion so vague (if not my poor English skills would...). In case I can't do anything prior to planning, so what I have done for two weeks is just searching through the internet finding nothing helpful even for my very general question.

Comment: No such package. Better to make your own by modifying the closest one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will find that the [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) in the laser_pipeline does exactly what you are looking for.

The `laser_scan_assembler` node accepts one topic as input. But you can remap or mux multiple laser scanners into that input topic and the assembler should be able to handle it. The algorithm should be using the actual headers from the incoming laser scans and consequently should be able to assemble them separately.

ALternatively you could just assemble the two scanners separately and then fuse the point clouds using the `point_cloud_assembler` node in the same package.

There's [a tutorial for using the package to assemble laser scans](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans)